# aspNetCompatibilityEnabled and non-HTTP bindings

Tags: asp.net, wcf, compatibility

We are Hosting a WCF Service in IIS, using netTcpbinding, webHttpBinding and wsHttpBinding.

> What is the effect on the non-HTTP bindings when I set
>   **aspNetCompatibilityEnabled** to true?

We need to enalbe the ASP.NET compatiblity for a custom Basic authentication implementation within a *IHttpModule*.

In the documentation of  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731336.aspx) ist written that non-HTTP bindings wont work:

> "aspNetCompatibilityEnabled: When this attribute is set to **true** ... communication over non-HTTP protocols is prohibited".

But when I enable the compatibility mode in the project, the net.tcp seems to work normal.
**Is is possible to have *aspNetCompatibilityEnabled* enabled and support *net.tcp* or *msmq* bindings?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that aspNetCompatibilityEnabled setting is actually enabled?
Are you checking the correct web.config?

It could be that you net.tcp service may be in a different project etc. Try to access HttpContext in your http web service to be sure that aspNetCompatibilityEnabled setting is actually working.

Comment: You are right. Compatibility Mode is somehow not working because HttpContext.Current is null. But I've checked again, the mode is enabled. I've also set the *AspNetCompatiblityRequirementsMode.Required*. Could be that because of the other non-HTTP bindings the compatibility mode cannot be started...?

Comment: Yup. That may be the cause.